# During the match at the beginning of Highlander, why does one of the fighters show off the Confederate flag?

Tags: highlander-franchise, highlander

Prior to the beginning of the match in Madison Square Garden, one of the fighters is wearing a cloak with the Confederate flag. Did the CSA (Confederate States of America) win the American Civil War in the *Highlander* timeline? If not, then for what purpose would a fighter wear the Confederate flag?

[image]

Comment: In the 80s it was not out-of-place to see the Confederate Flag as a general symbol of the South. See also the Dukes of Hazzard's iconic car etc. It's all over pop culture until, honestly, fairly recently, when it became even stronger of a political symbol. Being careful not to derail a movie question into politics.

Comment: You can see a confederate flag on a minnesotan ice house in Grumpy Old Men.  Prior to the 2000s it just meant the south or country music.  There's political ephemera for the Clinton + Gore ticket using it - I suspect that was the last time. To my generation I saw  it most in the Dukes of Hazzard and Matlock.  To someone in the South I was told it was so common it was basically background noise one wouldn't even notice. Of course obviously not everyone thought that.

Comment: The past is a different place; they do things differently there.

Comment: @JackAidley Must also be an alternate reality.  Because there can only be one (movie).  The suggestion of anything else is pure hogwash.

Comment: Are you aware of _today's_ people who still use the confederate flag much to others' disapproval? This question seems based on an assumption of no one wanting to use this flag anymore since the civil war ended.

Comment: @Flater: Not everyone is from the United States. Not everyone will be familiar with the intimate details of American culture.

Comment: @Kevin: My question was not intended to be snarky, it was a genuine question of OP's awareness and if they either weren't aware of it or assumed that the in-universe explanation for Highlander was a rewrite of history _regardless_ of real life. I'm not from the US either by the way.

Comment: @Kevin My understanding is that the confederate flag is used in lieu of banned symbols in Europe.  It's not just an American thing.

Comment: @JackAidley the original quote is "...a foreign country...", just FYI. https://www.goodreads.com/quotes/66426-the-past-is-a-foreign-country-they-do-things-differently

Answer (score 70):

Real professional wrestlers appeared in the beginning of the original Highlander film, including a three-man tag-team called [The Fabulous Freebirds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabulous_Freebirds).

The Freebirds performed through the 1980s, and into the 1990s. Since this was a team of Southern USA wrestlers, named after one of the best-known songs of the Southern rock band, Lynyrd Skynyrd. Confederate flags were a regular part of their in-the-ring characters' costume.

[image]

Comment: It was indeed part of their stage show; https://www.wrestlingnewsplus.com/michael-ps-hayes-explains-why-the-fabulous-freebirds-used-the-confederate-flags/. I've taken the liberty of adding in some footage from one of their shows.

Comment: From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fabulous_Freebirds):
"During this feud, as the Von Erichs would wave the flag of Texas, the Freebirds started using the flag of Georgia, which contained the Confederate battle flag, as a group symbol to counter it."